# R time series not plotting all data

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to print a random walk time series, it's very simple but the tail data won't print and the years appear as decimals.

```
library(astsa)
library(data.table)
x <- rnorm(104)
#Here it plots all points
plot.ts(x) 
#Here it won't plot past Q2/March
x_ts<-ts(x, start = c(2014,1,1), end = c(2015,12,31), frequency = 52)
plot.ts(x_ts)
```

Comment: From dataframe, create ts obj as such https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html

Comment: thanks for the condescending advice. If you can't help, please don't bother commenting. I'm still looking for help if someone else can assist.

Comment: from `?ts`: `start`: the time of the first observation. Either **a single number or a vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit**. So `c(2015,12,31)` means "12 weeks into 2015" -- not what you think  it means

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument to the start/end date should coincide with the frequency specified and reflects the time into that year. e.g. if the frequency is months, (2016, 3) is march. If the frequency is weeks, (2016, 12) is also march.